# Javascript Code Review: is it a good coding convention to write this way?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

Is it a good convention to write the following function:

```
const funcName = function funcName(){
....
}
```

I read that one should use function expressions and not function declarations, and it's a bad idea not to give a function a name. The problem I have is that I don't want to give a different name for a function and a different name for a variable, so I used the same name. Is it OK?

Comment: There is a time and a place for all coding styles. To make a blanket statement that function declarations are bad is reckless. With function expressions, you have the problem of hoisting that causes you to not be able to call a function before you declare it. If you don't use anonymous functions you lose a lot of flexibility. Also, this question will most likely get closed since it is not a programming problem that you need help with, which is what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: That dependeds on the code style you are using. For example: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#functions